# How to write this gradient as a vector?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

How to write this gradient as a vector using brackets []?
Is this:
$$
\operatorname{grad}f=(x\cos y−2)j+i\sin y
$$
equal to this:
$$
\operatorname{grad}f=[\sin y,x\cos y−2]\text{ ?}
$$

Thanks

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "using brackets"?

Comment: @Ric Ped 
edited - am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by normal vector? The gradient isn't anormal just because some people prefer to write it explicit as linear combination of the basis vectors (indeed, every vector is a linear combination of the basis vectors).

Comment: I meant a vector - I know a normal vector might be something different, fixed :)
and thanks for your notice.

Comment: @TomDavies92 yes, the answers are pretty clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to understand of this manner :

i : indicates the first coordinate

j: indicates the second

then : $grad f=  (sin \ y , x cos y - 2 )$

Answer (score 1):

Usually angled brackets are used to denote a vector, at least that is the convention I learned

$$ grad\; f = \left < f_x , f_y \right> = \left < \sin y , x \cos y - 2 \right>$$

Because parentheses and square brackets denote points and intervals. But there may be more than one way

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, vectors are more commonly expressed as columns with square brackets, e.g. $\mathbf{x} = \left[x_1, x_2, x_3\right]^T$. Angled brackets usually denote an inner product.